# Trouble adding appendix to ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm trying to add the appendix to my thesis and I've used the following commands:

```
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Performance Tables of ABCD}
\input{tab1}
\input{tab2}
\input{tab3}
\input{tab4}
\input{realworld}
\end{appendices}
```

And I've used the following package:

```
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
```

The problem is that it shows the following:

[image]

How can I get it to show just Appendix A? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Try using `\chapter*{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you [already have some definitions in your preamble regarding the way chapters are set in the ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151165/5764). As such, some minor adaptation listed below will allow you to switch off the `Chapter` insertion for the appendices:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\frontmatternumberline}{%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\@chapapp~##1\hfill\mbox{}\par\nobreak}}
\newcommand{\appendixnumberline}{%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{##1\hfill\mbox{}\par\nobreak}}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}% <cmd>
  {#1}% <search>
  {\frontmatternumberline #1}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{% Do the following when you hit \begin{appendices}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\frontmatternumberline\string\appendixnumberline}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\section{Problem definition}
\section{Genetic algorithms}
\section{Ant algorithms}
\section{Previous work}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{An appendix}
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}
\section{Last appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The use of `\string` - similar to `\protect` in this case - is to ensure that the macro insertions into the ToC do not expand.

Comment: Good solution, just came across this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With `\chapter*` the chapter should not appear in the TOC.

```
\begin{appendices}
\chapter*{Performance Tables of ABCD}
...
\end{appendices}
```

Comment: Doing that ends up removing the entry from the toc altogether apparently.

Comment: How about adding `\phantomsection` after `\begin{appendices}`?

Comment: That doesn't change the output either.

Comment: Then give `\chapter[]{Performance Tables of ABCD}` a try

Comment: That removes the performance tables part in the toc and just shows "Appendix Chapter A".

Comment: What documentclass are you using? In `book` for example it only says `Appendix A` in the TOC. Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
....
\mainmatter
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
....
\begin{appendices}
.....
\end{appendices}

\backmatter
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}

Not a working example but that's my layout.

Comment: If I compile this I get `Appendix A Performance...` in the TOC. Using `\chapter[]{...}` I get `Appendix A`. This is what you want right? It is important to have a MWE to figure out what's not going expectedly.

Comment: If you have an extra `Chapter` in your appendix title, you can redefine your appendix name with `\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}`

Comment: I had added this to the preamble:
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}% <cmd>
  {#1}% <search>
  {\def\numberline##1{\@chapapp~##1\hfill\mbox{}\par\nobreak}#1}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

Based on the question I had asked at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151165/custom-chapter-heading

Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that part adds a `Chapter` to the Appendix title, not sure what it does though...

Comment: I used it to change the default way latex displays chapter numbers and names.

Comment: removing `\@chapapp` from the `\patchcmd` removes the `Chapter` from the appendix title, but I assume it will mess with other chapter headings as well...

Comment: Yes. It shows Appendix A but all the chapters are shown as 1, 2 and so on instead of Chapter 1 Chapter 2

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the patch before beginning the appendix?